# extract the data from 2 files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files, the first file contain only 1 field, the second file has more lines than first file and also it has different field in each line.

File 1:

```
5
15
20
```

File 2:

```
3
5
O  1.25  2.30  3.75 
H  1.55  2.45  3.80
H  1.65  2.50  3.90
3
10
O  1.49  2.90  3.52
H  1.89  2.08  3.05
H  1.90  2.18  3.28
3
15
O  1.09  2.29  3.10
H  1.30  2.49  3.69
H  1.54  2.05  3.01
3
20
O  1.91  2.31  3.98 
H  1.64  2.96  3.04
H  1.07  2.49  3.49
```

in file 2, there is periodic loop, that the first line is number 3 and then second line is shows the number like 5,10,15,20, ... and the 3 lines that contain 4 field.

I want to compare two files and save the data when they have the same number, for example in file 1, first field is 5, I need to print the data from file 2 only!

correspond to the file 1 as an input and file 2 that I need to extract data, I would like to have the output like this:

```
3
5
O  1.25  2.30  3.75
H  1.55  2.45  3.80
H  1.65  2.50  3.90
3
15
O  1.09  2.29  3.10
H  1.30  2.49  3.69
H  1.54  2.05  3.01
3
20
O  1.91  2.31  3.98 
H  1.64  2.96  3.04
H  1.07  2.49  3.49
```

How I can have the output like this?
when FNR==NR, print the previous field and also FNR==NR and then the next three fields. because they are relating to each other and I would like to have them.
Thanks very much, 
Leila

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I removed the blank lines from your example. Please check and make sure that your input and output is shown correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
     a[$1];next
}
(FNR%10==3 && $1 in a){
     nr=FNR+9
}
(FNR<=nr || nr==""){
     print
}' file1 file2
```

Here I  assumed there is one blank line after each line.